# Ubuntu Emacs 26.3 svg image viewing not working

Tags: images

```
harold@cayse:~$ emacs --version
GNU Emacs 26.3
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GNU Emacs comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You may redistribute copies of GNU Emacs
under the terms of the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING.
```

I am setting up a new machine, and svg image display is not working.

All I can get is this small empty square:
[image]

Editing it as text works `ctrl-C-C`:
[image]

As do other image formats:
[image]

Errors like this show up in `*messages*`:

```
ImageMagick error: unable to open file `/tmp/magick-11959NkcV4z0af4jD': No such file or directory @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544
```

Not sure what to try next, thanks in advance for your time and consideration.

Comment: Do `ldd $(command -v emacs) | grep svg` - does it show anything? If not, then your emacs is probably not capable of showing SVG files. You might have to rebuild with the appropriate library (in my case (Fedora 31), that is `librsvg2-devel` - that's probably similar in your case, but I don't know for sure).

Comment: Thanks, yes, that doesn't return anything, so that seems related for sure. I installed it using the normal ubuntu "Software" program, but there are some other slightly funny things about this system, so I won't blame anyone but myself. Thanks for the hint.